# How to align text in DataTable cell in c# from .cs file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatable

I have created a table as

```
 DataTable table= new DataTable();
```

in which I am adding data row by row.But in one row the first column is string and other columns are digits.
I want to align the first column to left and the digits to right.Is there any way to align a cell while adding into the row?

Comment: A `DataTable` stores data, it has no formatting at all. You cannot align columns, i assume you're confusing the `DataTable` with a `DataGrid` where you show the content of the table.

Comment: Do we show `DataTable` to end-user? No. Then how come formatting comes into play?

Comment: I am binding the datatable to the xaml directly and my data is coming up  properly , its just i want to align it.

Comment: Which DataGrid You Are using any third party Controls? and do u have XAML code for it?

Comment: I am using RadGridView , it is a telerik control, Yes i have xaml code.

Answer (score -2):

In

```
<Window.Resources>
```

Write following code:

```
<Style x:Key="RightCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewCell}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right">
    </Setter>

</Style>

<Style x:Key="LeftCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewCell}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left">
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In

```
<telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
```

write following code i.e set the style to the cell

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Your header" CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftCellStyle }"></telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

and same for cell where you want right alignment; just set

```
CellStyle="{StaticResource RightCellStyle }"
```

Tell me whether its what you were looking for?

Comment: No this is not what I want.